# How to insert html text in XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a XML that contains an html code just like:

```
<description>
   &lt;p&gt;This is an very cute tiny bear!&lt;/p&gt
</description>
```

how to transform this with XSLT:

```
<div>
   <p>This is an very cute tiny bear!</p>
</div>
```

the p tag will be regard as html tags.

Comment: You could do `<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />` but this may not always be supported (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping). For example, it would not would not work in Firefox if you were doing the transformation on the client, rather than on the server.

Comment: it is not support by XSLT processor

Comment: Do you want to use it in a asp.net page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this code by saxon XSLT processor. It works properly.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <div>
         <xsl:value-of select="/description" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </div>
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

see http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuNT

Comment: Good one dear. Keep it.